# Scheduled task for update ADUser did not update user

Tags: active-directory, powershell, scheduled-task

i'm write powershell script for update userthumbnailPhoto.
I'm use Get-ADObject and Set-ADObject for thistask.

When i run script under logged in user - script work fine and update AD user.

When i make scheduled task, and run script - script work, but Set-ADObject does not change anything. Task created to run with same user credentials when logged on or not. Also i trying set "run with hight privilegies"

Why it's may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug it with try/catch like:

```
Try {
Set-Mailbox <...........> -ErrorAction stop
}
Catch {
$_ | Out-File c:\script.log -Append
}
```